# Weird results from cypher collaborative filter query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using one of the neo4j practice graphs (see below) to learn cypher
and running a query to search for people who both acted int and directed a movie, I'm running the following commands:

```
:play movie graph

MATCH (p:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[d:DIRECTED]-(p)
RETURN p,m,a,d,type(a),type(d)
```

I few things don't make sense:

- for some rows in the result `type(a)` is not `ACTED_IN` but
  `PRODUCER` or `WROTE` etc.
- a lot of nodes are returned which don't seem to satisfy this pattern
- using `OPTIONAL MATCH` works exactly right but I don't know why?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: update: I think this is a bug as the query works as expected in the sandbox version in the browser where as I am using the desktop version

Comment: It is better to add the update in your question directly. Other guys will see it directly instead of looking for update in comments.

Comment: @James Please create a new [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for what seems to be a serious bug.

Answer (score 1):

As cybersam commented, this definitely looks like a bug in the compiled runtime.

If you PROFILE this you can see it's using compiled runtime; if you prefix the query with `CYPHER runtime=slotted` we get expected results.

I'll pass this along to the cypher team.